# Close status bar when opened: Android

Tags: android, statusbar

I am trying to come up with some ways of disabling the status bar without hiding it completely. This is an introlude attempt at disabling status bars in 3rd party apps. For now, I want to disable it in my own app, and then eventually create a background service to see if I can do so in other apps. The app I am creating is an operating system for children, and I am trying to develop a closed system.

Here is what I have tried. My initial idea was to monitor when status bar was accessed and then closing it.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged()");
    try {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            Log.d(TAG, "close status bar attempt");
            Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
            Class<?> statusbarManager = Class
                    .forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
            collapse.setAccessible(true);
            collapse.invoke(service);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method I used. It works for detecting when status bar is being accessed, however, it does not close the status bar once it has focus. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found answer to my question. First, I was missing the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

With that permission, the following code now works really well.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged()");
    try {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            Log.d(TAG, "close status bar attempt");
            //option 1
            int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
            Class<?> statusbarManager = Class
                    .forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");

            if (currentApiVersion <= 16) {
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                collapse.setAccessible(true);
                collapse.invoke(service);
            } else {
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                collapse.setAccessible(true);
                collapse.invoke(service);
            }
            // option 2
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            mContext.sendBroadcast(it); 

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you notice, there is a second option as well that I found to be working good. You can comment out option 1 if you want to use option 2, or vise versa. Both accomplish the same thing, although I believe option 2 is better.

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
mContext.sendBroadcast(it);
```

The only downfall I found is that it is slow(er) when closing. However, both methods collapse quick enough to where no one can click on any notifications or options in the status bar. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else. Good luck, Cheers!

Comment: What exactly does this accomplish? If I understood correctly then with this code, as soon as the user tries to access the status bar, it will immediately collapse?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it does. Now I can create background service with this collapse code and hopefully status bar will collapse even if user is using 3rd party app. Remember my app is a launcher app (operating system). This will be a big piece of the puzzle for creating a closed system where user cannot go to places they shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: I am also working on a closed kiosk and I was going to go a much longer route. My app is also a launcher. Does this close the status bar quick enough so that the user can't be nifty and quickly press settings or something? This will be really helpful to me also and I will probably incorporate this in my app if it is this easy. Are you using this code in a service?

Comment: Yep, it is quick enough. I have been trying the past 5 mins (because I just figured this out), and I have not successfully been able to click anything. And yes, I set this up in a service. So far things are working. I did make some alterations though. Let me post my improvement logic.

Comment: Could you please provide me the code for this service? Atleast the barebones to incorporate into my application so that I don't have to go through the same struggle as you? I can ask a question if you like and mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Ok, send me the post link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872487/how-to-make-a-service-to-automatically-shut-the-status-bar-when-user-tries-to-ac

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64731/discussion-between-qazi-ahmed-and-portfoliobuilder).

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on the same thing. With Android 5.0 Lolipop they have released Screen Pinning mode (which is essentially Kiosk mode) which does a few things:

- The status bar is blank, and user notifications and status information are hidden.
- The Home and Recent Apps buttons are hidden.
- Other apps cannot launch new activities.
- The current app can start new activities, as long as doing so does not create new tasks.
- When screen pinning is invoked by a device owner, the user remains locked to your app until the app        calls stopLockTask().
- If screen pinning is activity by another app that is not a device owner or by the user directly, the user can exit by holding both the Back and Recent buttons.

You can read about it further in the [Android 5.0 Lolipop release documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html).

However, if you are looking for a more controlable solution, then you may want to create a custom ROM. Here is a great overview on making Kiosk applications (which also require disabling status bar).

[Developing Kiosk Mode Applications in Android Tutorial](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/11/developing-kiosk-mode-applications-in-android/)

Comment: Great response. I will look into this. My concern is that I have to make this for API 16 compatibility. For now, this methodology seems to be working well. It is just inconsistent, sometimes it closes quickly, other times it does slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer if anyone is still looking for a solution to something like this: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

For me, I added the following in my onResume() method:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

This allows the status bar to stay hidden but the user can still access it by swiping the edge of the screen.  Then after a few seconds of inactivity it will collapse and disappear again!