# How to lock settings in applock lock application without locking bluetooth and wifi options?

Tags: android, applocker

I am developing an applock type app in android, where there is a requirement to lock settings without locking the bluetooth-wifi options from quick menu. For eg when i lock the settings and enebale bluetooth or wifi from quick menu,it shows lock screen before getting the list of bluetooth devices. How can I overcome this situation. I've heard about doing some changes in local system.db but only works in rooted os. I want to know to do to this in both rooted and nonrooted os.

thanks

Comment: I've seen that samsung mobile gives me "com.android.settings" pkg name when i open bluetooth options from quick menu while cynogenmod doesn't give me any package name,so actually app warks fine in cynogenmod but not in native os. Or is there a way to knoow that quick menu option is opened or status bar is dragged down

Comment: Or is there a way to knoow that quick menu option is opened or status bar is dragged down. Also there is a way to detect notification drawer is dragged or not so to disable app durng that time as per :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871487/close-status-bar-when-opened-android. but how to use onWindowFocusChanged() in a service